# How can an object be null and not null at the same time?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, c#-6.0

So I have this bit of code, if I break point on the `return` statement the immediate window outputs the information below.

```
try
{
    await connection.OpenAsync();
    var obj = await cmd.ExecuteScalarAsync();
    return obj != null ? Int32.Parse(obj.ToString()) != 1 : false;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Log.Error("An error has occurred checking a customer/product authorization.", ex);
    return false;
}
finally
{
    connection.Close();
}
```

**Stored Procedure**
Here is the relevant parts of the stored procedure. @HasAuthTable and @IsAuthorized are of the type `bit`.

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN @HasAuthTable = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) | @IsAuthorized AS IsAuthorized
```

**Immediate Window**

```
obj
0

obj == null
false

obj != null
false

obj == 0
error CS0019: Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'object' and 'int'

obj != 0
error CS0019: Operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'object' and 'int'

(int)obj == 0
true

(int)obj != 0
false

obj.GetType().FullName
"System.Int32"

obj.Equals(null)
false

!obj.Equals(null)
true

Object.ReferenceEquals(obj, null)
false

!Object.ReferenceEquals(obj, null)
false
```

I've tried *Rebuilding* the solution didn't change anything. I have also tried restarting Visual Studio. No luck. Is this intended behavior? It seems like a bug.

**Altered Stored Procedure**
I tried changing the output of the stored procedure to match the following to see if it affects it in any way. The result is basically the same. static type of `object` with the expected dynamic type, both having values but still returning `false` for `obj == null` and `obj != null`.

```
SELECT CAST(((CASE WHEN @HasAuthTable = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) | @IsAuthorized) AS BIT) AS IsAuthorized
```

**Respective Immediate Window**

```
obj
false

obj != null
false

obj == null
false

obj.GetType().FullName
"System.Boolean"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can DBNull not equal DBNull](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2060217/how-can-dbnull-not-equal-dbnull)

Comment: @Eris If the value was `DBNull.Value` then `obj` wouldn't resolve to `0` and `obj != null` would be `true` not `false`.

Comment: Use a debugger to inspect the type of obj .

Comment: @Ian It's `int`, as you can see from the edit

Comment: If it's an `int` then `obj != null` should be `true`

Comment: Hmm either it's a weird interaction with `SqlConnection/SqlCommand` or it's a visual studio bug then right? Can't say this isn't the first time Visual Studio 2015 has done really weird things (even after reinstalls).

Comment: Is `obj != null` `true` when actually running the code, rather than using the debugger?

Comment: Nope. If I do `object obj = 0;` in C# interactive then `obj != null` is true, but when I run my code it still returns false. Could it be related to how I'm returning my value from the stored procedure?

Comment: I suspect the immediate window has got confused because of the cast to int above. The error message error CS0019: Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'object' and 'int' suggests that it isn't an int at that stage.

Comment: @Ian No, that's based entirely on the compile time types of the left and right operands; that's all exactly what it ought to be.  The only erroneous result is that `obj != null` should be `true` not `false`.

Comment: @Shelby115 what does `obj.GetType().FullName` return in the `Respective Immediate Window`?

Comment: If this was JavaScript the answer would be that `obj` is `undefined`

Comment: @MatiasCicero If this was JavaScript an extra `=` symbol would probably clear this weirdness right up.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3507383/equalsitem-null-or-item-null -- Take away use Object.ReferenceEquals(item, null);

Comment: @Shelby115 if its a `boolean` then its not nullable, should it still be returning `true` or `false` for either of the null checks?

Comment: @AlexKrupka `obj` is a variable of type `object`, so we know that there's no custom `==` operator messing this up.

Comment: @Servy `obj` is a variable of type `System.Boolean` isn't it?

Comment: @BackDoorNoBaby No, it's a boxed integer.

Comment: @Servy why does the immediate window say its a boolean?

Comment: @BackDoorNoBaby It depends on which immediate window you look at. There's one as an integer and one as a boolean. I've tried both it's doing it in both scenarios. ("Immedaite Window" vs "Respective Immediate Window").

Comment: @Shelby115 I imagine in the "Immediate Window" its saying that because you cast it to an `int` prior to asking for the type, but in "Respective Immediate Window" the type is `boolean` without any casting. What am I missing here?

Comment: @BackDoorNoBaby These are 2 separate debugging sessions. The first is the original (integer), the second was an attempt to cast the stored procedure's output to a bit/boolean. Both end up giving me an object that has a value and type but returns false for both `obj == null` and `obj != null` which should be impossible.

Comment: @Shelby115 ahh okay, my apologies for the confusion

Comment: I've submitted the issue to Microsoft via `Help - Send Feedback - Report an Issue`. At this point I'm pretty confident that it is a bug with visual studio. Thank you all for confirming my suspicion.

Comment: just use `return obj + "" == "1";` because `null + ""` and `DBNull.Value + ""` both result in `""`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`var obj = await cmd.ExecuteScalarAsync();` is doing **Boxing**.

[image]

***Immediate Window displays incorrect value if 0 is boxed.*** It must be a bug in Immediate Window.

[image]

*The picture is from [Illustrated C# 2012 4th Edition by Daniel Solis](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430242787).*

Comment: The immediate window reflects what happens in the code. So when it reaches `return obj != null ? Int32.Parse(obj.ToString()) != 1 : false;` `obj != null` returns false (even those it's not null). I'm aware I could technically at this point just remove the `obj != null` check but I was curious if this was some new/weird intentional behavior or a bug.

Comment: Immediate windows has a bug. It doesn't match up the result if boxing value is 0. Look at the updated screenshot which return.

Comment: I have [reported the Immediate window bug on the Roslyn repo](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/12846).